# How do I get a small jQuery component?

Tags: jquery, performance, compression, minify

Let's say I make a very small script and only use a few jQuery functions. Now I don't want to have the user load the entire jQuery library of about 87kb, how can I get a smaller jQuery script with only the methods I need?

An example of a small script.

```
$(document).ready( function() {


  $(window).scroll(function() {
    var $wScroll = $(this).scrollTop();

    if ($wScroll <= 400) {
      $("header")
      .css({
        "transform" : "translate3d(0,"+ $wScroll /250 +"rem, 0)"
      })
      .css({
        "opacity" : + 1.8 - $wScroll / 200
      });
    };
  });
});
```

Comment: use pure jjavascript instead of jquery

Comment: For this instance that would work. But as my JavaScript knowledge don't cover all what jQuery can do for me. I would still have this problem if I used some more difficult methods and I'd be back here asking the same.

Comment: If you don't know what your dependencies are going to be, there's no magic bullet. You have to hunt them down and copy them from the jquery script.
87kb isn't that bad anyway, considering the browser will cache it after the first load.